# Android Developing: notifications don't show when app is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-notifications, android-alarms

How can I send scheduled notifications in Android Studio?
I got this task: I want to get notifications at the some chosen time of the day every day. I can easily get them when app is alive, but when its closed notifications don't come up.

I've already tried JobScheduler, AlarmManager and WorkManager and none of these didn't work well.
My project runs at minimum SDK 26 (Android Oreo). Target SDK is 30. Last code version looks like that:

**AlertReceiver.java**

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        showNotifications();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void showNotifications(){
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getApplicationContext());

        NotificationCompat.Builder nb;

        nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification("Title", "Description");
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(123, nb.build());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

I schedule the alert like so:

````
        ...
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        alarm_manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
```
````

Comment: why are you using `NotificationHelper`?

Comment: @isthemartin I tried a lot of different suggestions for my task. One of these suggestions (which is the last one I've tried yet) had that code. Also I tried to call notifications directly from alarm manager, without any re-direct to other classes (such as notification helper etc.)

Comment: Hi Dkezling. What are you getting in logcat? I would expect to see something similar to: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent, app is in background".

Comment: @Elletlar yeah I got this couple of times. I google that problem and got some suggestions like "use job scheduler" to fix that. But job scheduler didn't work well same as other methods - Job Scheduler didn't work after app gets closed.

Comment: I made a change to your current implementation below. It should at least let the service run from the background, but whether it is the solution that you want I don't know. It sounds like what you really want to use is Firebase Cloud Messaging if possible.

Comment: @Elletlar does Firebase Cloud Messaging work without internet connection?

Comment: No it cannot deliver messages without an internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that from Android 8 calling `startService` from the background is not allowed:

In this code:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

You can change from:

```
context.startService(intent);
```

To:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), intent)
```

And put this in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

This will at least allow your service to run from the background in your current implementation.

You then have 5 seconds to call `startForeground()` in your `Service` and post a `Notification` that lets the user know that your service is running or it will be terminated.

Also for what you are trying to do, I think you will get a better result with:

```
setExactAndAllowWhileIdle
```

Or

```
setAlarmClock
```

`setExact` does not work as the name implies. All the AlarmManager documentation needs to be read carefully and I would suggest studying "doze" in detail before attempting any `Service` implementations that rely on timing.

Comment: It has foreground service notification - is there any way to hide it/not to show it? I read some suggestions about that thing and some of them says that thats illegal due the Google Market Policy.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Google made it mandatory so that the user is always aware when a service is running in the background. However, there are some tricks like setting it to low priority and setting it as private so it never appears on the lock screen.

Comment: If your Service only needs to run very briefly then you may be able to get away with not calling startForeground() and instead calling stopSelf() before the 5 second limit expires. I have never tried that since I do not have any services that trivial. It seems ill advisable, but maybe technically possible. But in general, it is best to use one of the canned solutions like WorkManager if at all possible even though they generally don't suit the original specification that developers have in mind timing wise.

Comment: I can confirm in 2022 that this does not work anymore. Google needs to fix its notifications. That's the main reason why we make mobile apps for, notifications! If not, web apps are just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a notification that I used in a project (sorry for Kotlin language):

```
private fun createNotification() {
    val notification = getServiceNotification("")
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build())
}

private fun getServiceNotification(contentText: String): Notification.Builder {
    var notification = Notification.Builder(this)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createNotificationChannel()
        notification = Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID)
    }

    val openAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    return notification
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_main)
        .setContentIntent(openAppPendingIntent)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID,
        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    ).apply {
        lightColor = Color.GREEN
        lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
    }

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
}
```

Comment: that works same for me but didn't you use the scheduled notifications? code you sent there just shows how to use notifications, not how to schedule them after app is closed.